# Randomizing an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I wish to implement the Dr.D.E.Knuth's Subtractive RANDOM number generation algorithm. I wish to implement an ATM panel on which when very time user log-in the buttons will be scrambled. every button will change its position.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub addbutton()
        Dim n As Integer = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            ' Initialize one variable
            btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Next i

        While (n < 10)
            With (btnArray(n))
                .Tag = n + 1 ' Tag of button
                .Width = 40 ' Width of button
                .Height = 40
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btnArray(n))
                .Text = Chr(n + 48)
                AddHandler .Click, AddressOf Me.ClickButton
                n += 1
            End With
        End While
    End Sub
```

Then, for sending information to button Text, I used:

```
 Dim btn As Button = sender
        TextBox1.Text += btn.Text
```

Now the major task is to shuffle the `btnArray()` with `Random()` function.. But I've failed to do this. I managed to get some code for shuffling the array like follows:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class ArrayUtilities
    Private Random As RNGCryptoServiceProvider = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    Private Bytes(4) As Byte

    Public Function ShuffleArray(ByVal argArr As Array) As Array
        Dim FirstArray As New ArrayList(argArr)
        Dim SecoundArray As Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Object), FirstArray.Count)
        Dim intIndex As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To FirstArray.Count - 1
            intIndex = RandomNumber(FirstArray.Count)
            SecoundArray(i) = FirstArray(intIndex)
            FirstArray.RemoveAt(intIndex)
        Next
        FirstArray = Nothing
        Return SecoundArray
    End Function

    Private Function RandomNumber(ByVal argMax As Integer) As Integer
        If argMax <= 0 Then Throw New Exception
        Random.GetBytes(Bytes)
        Dim intValue As Integer = (BitConverter.ToInt32(Bytes, 0)) Mod argMax
        If intValue < 0 Then intValue = -intValue
        Return intValue
    End Function
End Class

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim AU As ArrayUtilities

        AU = New ArrayUtilities

        Dim GivenArray As Integer() = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        Dim NewArray As Array = AU.ShuffleArray(GivenArray)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim stb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        stb.Append("GivenArray = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}")
        stb.Append(vbCrLf)
        stb.Append("NewArray = {")
        For i = 0 To NewArray.Length - 2
            stb.Append(NewArray(i).ToString)
            stb.Append(", ")
        Next
        stb.Append(NewArray(NewArray.Length - 1).ToString)
        stb.Append("}")
        Console.Write(stb.ToString)
        Console.Read()
    End Sub
End Module
```

### Yet, when we debug this code we get RANDOMNESS for the array. In the same way, I want randomness for my buttons on form.

Thank you sir. sir i tried the code that u suggested.
I was missing the incremental character "n".
Tthe debug-able code is 
flowlayoutpannel.controls.add(out(n)). 
but it is not working as i wanted and ABOVE code is just to show the way i want 2 shuffle the BUTTONS. 
Is there any simpler way to jst create an button array and randomize them with RANDOM() and adding to form.
My buddies says you are so stupid that u are working on this topic from last 20-25DAYS

Comment: Some coding tips: `= 0 To 10` -> `= 0 To 9`; `New System.Windows.Forms.Button` -> `Button`; `While (n < 10)` -> `While n < 10`; `With (btnArray(n))` -> `With btnArray(n)`; use a `For` loop instead of a `While` loop.

Comment: So, can you explain what it is you actually want to accomplish, please?

Comment: Dear Sir, I wish to implement the Dr.D.E.Knuth's Subtractive RANDOM number generation algorithm. I wish to implement an ATM panel on which when very time user log-in the buttons will be scrambled. every button will change its position. we can try this out with changing its associate text too. but the randomness must be accomplish.

Comment: @sanket_7592 I moved the majority of your comment _into_ the question, and made some edits for clarity and grammar. Please check my edit to ensure the question accurately reflects the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My basic NEED is : I want to declare an ARRAY of BUTTON and place them on flow-layout panel then shuffle the text from the button with RANDOM() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some "shuffle" algorithms (search Fisher-Yates for example) and they are usually not difficult to implement. The EASIEST (imho) way, ist to use LINQ:

```
Dim r As New Random
Dim out = (From b In btnArray Order By r.Next Select b).ToArray
```

Maybe the question is not clear: Do you want to shuffle the POSITIONS of the buttons or do you want to shuffle the CONTENT (buttons) of the Array?

Comment: Thank you sir for reply. Sir, i want to shuffle the CONTENT of array. so that i can implement Dr.D.E.Knuth's Subtractive RANDOM number generation algorithm in better way. If shuffling position solves my issue then no problem problem.

Comment: Sir, when i tried the code like this flowlayoutpannel.controls.add(out) it shows " Value of '1-dimentional array of System.Windows.Forms.Button' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: Thank you sir. sir i tried the code that u suggested. I was missing the incremental character "n". Tthe debug-able code is flowlayoutpannel.controls.add(out(n)). but it is not working as i wanted and ABOVE code is just to show the way i want 2 shuffle the BUTTONS. Is there any simpler way to jst create an button array and randomize them with RANDOM() and adding to form. My buddies says you are so stupid that u are working on this topic from last 20-25DAYS
arrays vb.net

Answer (score 0):

To set the position of the buttons randomly in the panel, instead of using n from 0 to 9 in the loop, you can use a random value from 0 to 9. Be sure you don't use the same value twice.

Comment: Thank you sir for reply but i am working on Dr.D.E.Knuth's Subtractive RANDOM number generation algorithm so its necessary for me to dynamically shuffle the buttons.

Comment: One way to do that is to use an array of buttons, then shuffle an index array. When you're finished shuffling, display based on the index array. For example, use button(ix(i)) to access the buttons, then shuffle ix so ix(i) is the ith random number.

Comment: Thank you sir, but in VB.NET PROGRAMMING ENVIRONMENT, it return casting error for conversion of INTEGER array into BUTTON.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a cryptographically secure random number generator for that, nor do you need a separate class.

```
Private Shared rng As New Random()

Private Shared Function ShuffleArray(Of T)(arr() As T) As T()
    Dim left = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).ToList()
    Dim result(arr.Length - 1) As T

    For i = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        Dim nextIndex = rng.Next(left.Count)
        result(i) = arr(left(nextIndex))
        left.RemoveAt(nextIndex)
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you sir. sir i tried the code that u suggested. i was missing the incremental character "n". the debug-able code is flowlayoutpannel.controls.add(out(n)).

Comment: I want to just shuffle the names of button.
How can we shuffle the .text=char(n+48)