# How can I stop an array from repeating in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random

I have randomized an array, so questions are shown in a different order every time that the quiz is played, but would prefer it if the questions weren't able to repeat.

Here is how my array is set up:

```
Function loadQuestions()

    Questions(0).Question = "Which of these words are an adjective?"
    Questions(0).option1 = "Dog"
    Questions(0).option2 = "Beautiful"
    Questions(0).option3 = "Steven"
    Questions(0).option4 = "Bird"
    Questions(0).Answer = "B"

    Questions(1).Question = "What's the adjective in this sentence:" & vbCrLf & "'Kelly handled the breakable glasses very carefully'"
    Questions(1).option1 = "Kelly"
    Questions(1).option2 = "Handled"
    Questions(1).option3 = "Carefully"
    Questions(1).option4 = "Breakable"
    Questions(1).Answer = "D"
    ...
```

This is the function that calls the questions when the quiz begins.

```
Function GetQuestion(ByVal intQuestion As Integer)

    tmrOne.Start()

    If questionNumber < 11 Then
        lblQuestionNumber.Text = "Question" & " " & questionNumber
        Dim questionChosen As Integer
        questionChosen = random.Next(25)
        lblQuestion.Text = Questions(questionChosen).Question
        btnAnswerA.Text = Questions(questionChosen).option1
        btnAnswerB.Text = Questions(questionChosen).option2
        btnAnswerC.Text = Questions(questionChosen).option3
        btnAnswerD.Text = Questions(questionChosen).option4
        strAnswer = Questions(questionChosen).Answer

        questionNumber = questionNumber + 1
        btnAnswerA.BackColor = Color.White
        btnAnswerB.BackColor = Color.White
        btnAnswerC.BackColor = Color.White
        btnAnswerD.BackColor = Color.White
        btnAnswerA.Enabled = True
        btnAnswerB.Enabled = True
        btnAnswerC.Enabled = True
        btnAnswerD.Enabled = True
        Return intQuestion
    Else
        MsgBox("You have finished")
        End
    End If

End Function
```

I have tried to find something on the internet to help with this, but haven't been successful or understood it as I am new to this. I have found ArrayList.RemoveAt but not sure that is the correct syntax to use with my array?

So, how do I stop my array from repeating a question once it has already been asked? Do I put them into another array?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already asked this question.  Same [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13340213/17034).

Comment: Hans Passant is right, you shouldn't be posting equivalent questions over and over; you should have waited until the right answer would come to your previous question (by editing the question further and performing work/research by your own). In any case, I don't fully agree with this being a duplicate of the provided link; because it deals with arrays (more complicated). With Lists/ArrayLists things become much easier (as shown in my answer). The problem is not even the same with perhaps the trickiest issue (avoiding repeated elements): with Lists + RemoveAt you get rid of it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you are using an `ArrayList`. In that case, yes, the `RemoveAt` option sounds as the best alternative. Bear in mind that pure arrays (e.g., `Dim Questions() As String`) are the most efficient type of `Collection`; the main advantage of `Lists`/`ArrayLists` is precisely how easy is adding/removing elements, so if you use an ArrayList, better maximising one of its defining features.

The additional advantage in your specific case is that every time you remove an item, its position is filled (and the total number of items decreased). Thus, you have just to update the maximum value of your random number generator to the current number of indices (not elements, because the first index is zero).

In summary, the following changes in your code will deliver what you want:

```
If(Questions.Count > 0) Then
    questionChosen = random.Next(0, Questions.Count - 1)
End If
```

And once you are done with it:

```
If(questionChosen >= 0 And questionChosen <= Questions.Count - 1) Then
    Questions.RemoveAt(questionChosen)
End If
```